# How to generate array object from pojo and pass in formparams in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, multipartform-data, rest-assured

I need to generate key as `customerContactList[0].customerContactId` from Pojo. I have tried with arrayList but I am able to generate in below format `customerContactList=[{ customerContactId=2 } ]` which seems invalid for API request.

- this Post API accept form-data
- If I pass in key value pair `formParams.put("customerContactList[0].customerContactId", 2);` then it is consider as valid. But I need to generate same format through Pojo.

Answer (score 0):

Your standard pojo should look like this.

```
{
  "customerContactList": [
    {
      "customerContactId": 2
    },
    {
      "customerContactId": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

May be this will help you.

```
class Pojo {
    List<CustomerContact> customerContactList;
}

class CustomerContact {
    int customerContactId;
}
```

Comment: I had tried in same way also, after this I have created object of Pojo class and in parameterize constructor I have pass that array object. After that I am converting that java object to Map for key value pair. But it does not generate key which I require to pass as per my question.